# binary numbers (palindrome)

Tags: binary, palindrome

"A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or other sequence of characters which reads the same backward or forward."
Should we consider 2015 in binary format (111 1101 1111) a palindrome? This is feasible if we can neglect the leftmost 0, but can we do that? I mean in binary each four bits correspond to a decimal digit so we must have a leftmost zero which makes 2015 = 2000+0+10+5 = 0111 1101 0000+0000+1010+0101 = 0111 1101 1111 so can it be considered a palindrome? I know this can seem a dump theoretical question but I want to know the answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, I was thinking,according to how most modern computers work (using the binary coded decimal(BCD)), that because each two decimal digits are encoded within a single byte by taking advantage of the fact that four bits are enough to represent the range 0 to 9, I thought I should put our binary number in four-bit chunks, I mean to be able to represent it in a byte so I thought it will be inappropriate not to complete the most left chunk by adding one zero, you know, if we followed that logic then, 2015 should not be considered a palindrome. should it? that is my question.

Comment: does a computer neglect it?

Comment: Well of course if you ask "is it a palindrome in BCD", then no.

Answer (score 1):

11111011111 binary is 2015 decimal, and **adding 0's to the left doesn't change its value**. Note that you also mentioned: "in binary each four bits corresponds to a decimal digit". That's not the case. Here's an example of how binary corresponds to decimal:

[image]

**So yes, you can neglect the leftmost 0.** And 2015 is a palindrome.